# Tweaking of a preg_replace string to hide the decimals of a price

Tags: php, preg-replace, currency, decimal

I have this code:

```
$string = '/([\d,]+)\.(\d+)(.*)$/';

$condition = preg_replace($string, '$2', $price);

if ($condition == 00) {

$show = preg_replace($string, '$1$3', $price);

} else {

$show = preg_replace($string, '$1.$2$3', $price);

}
```

So, if I have the price in this format: **100.00€** after the code is executed, the price is shown like this: **100€**

But if I have the price in this format: **$100.00** after the code is executed, the price is still shown like this: **$100.00** i.e. the **00** is not trimmed (the second **$show** after the **else** statement is loaded).

The **$price** is generated with the currency symbol all together, so it's not just a pure number.

Any suggestions how can I make this happen, regardless the currency postion (left or right)?

Thanks.

**P.S.** It doesn't need to be this code, you can suggest another one, as long as it makes the 00 decimals to dissapear if equal to zero, regardles the position of the currecy symbol.

Comment: Is there any reason why something like `str_replace(".00", "", $string)` would not suffice?

Comment: @salathe - Your comment is probably the most reasonable, and it hadn't even occurred to me until as I was walking back from work. If the string is guaranteed to be rounded to 2 decimal places, yours is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$num = 126.54;
echo $num === round($num, 0) ? round($num, 0) : $num;
?>
```

That can be used to spit out your number. As far as currency position, you can set up a conditional for that depending on what the currency is.

**FULL ANSWER:** This handles all currency types and places them in their correct positions. Enjoy:

```
<?php
$symbols = array('€', '$');
$price = '$126.56';

foreach($symbols as $needle)
{
    if($pos = strpos($price, $needle) && $pos !== false)
        break;
}

$num = floatval(str_replace($symbols, '', $price));
$num = $num === round($num, 0) ? round($num, 0) : $num;

echo $pos ? $num.substr($price, -1) : substr($price, 0, 1).$num;
?>
```

**KISS Method:** Sometimes, we get so caught up in the complexities of answers, we lose sight of the simple ones. I know this is a little late, but it could potentially blow away a lot of unnecessary code. Use this ONLY if you are guaranteed to have two decimal places in your pricing:

```
<?php
$rounded = str_replace('.00', '', $price);
?>
```

What this will do is effectively eliminate any need to worry about Currency placement. But remember: This ONLY works for your case if you are guaranteed a pricing format of exactly two decimal places.

Comment: The "problem" is that the $price is generated with the currency symbol all together, so it's not just a pure number, that's why I can't use your solution, which is very useful though.

Comment: The FULL ANSWER code works, but not as it should :) The $100 is ok, but the euro is shown like this: 1100 i.e. without the € sign, and it also adds the first number in front, as you can see :) 500.00€ would be shown like this: 5500

Comment: Strange. Testing on my own server, it was outputting things as expected. Looking into this.

Comment: How are you utilizing this example? I'm getting 126.56€ and $126.56 on my own end.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

**UPDATE**

Misread your original post and didn't realize you wanted to keep the currency symbol. This should do the trick nice and simple, and it doesn't matter what currency symbol it is, or where it is.

```
// Won't change this
$number = '$200.00';
echo preg_replace('/([.0-9]+)(€)/e','round(\'$1\',0)."$2"',$number);

// Will change this
$number = '200.00€';
echo preg_replace('/([.0-9]+)(€)/e','round(\'$1\',0)."$2"',$number);
```

Comment: It's not working, i.e. it doesn't change the price at all. I also can't get what you mean by: "Won't change this" and "Will change this", because you said: "it doesn't matter what currency symbol it is, or where it is", so if it's like that, why it won't change the $, and it will change the €? :)